# Run Invoke-Command in remote computer as administrator

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to run invoke-command to launch a `powershell script in a powershell file` on a `remote computer`. I'm using the `credentials for a user with Administrator privilege`. The command needs to be executed by `running powershell as an administrator`. There are licensing issues with the application that i'm trying to invoke using the powershell script, so i cannot change the credentials to Administrator but need to run with that particular user itself. I have tried using `-RunAsAdministrator` at the end of the Invoke-Command, but i got an error saying:

`Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

```
$command = {
    cd Folder
    C:\Folder\build.ps1
} 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteSystemIP -ScriptBlock $command -credential $Credentials1 -ErrorAction Stop -AsJob
```

I'm trying to execute this as a background job that's why i added the `-AsJob` parameter.

Its been several days and i haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The only way to get a remote PowerShell session to execute elevated (with admin privileges) is to connect with a user account (either implicitly or via `-Credential`) that has admin privileges on the target machine.
- With such an account, the session automatically and invariably runs elevated.

---

The [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s **`-RunAsAdministrator`** switch **can only be used with (virtualization) *containers* (`-ContainerId` parameter)**, not regular remoting (`-ComputerName` parameter).

You **cannot elevate *on demand* in a remote session** (the way you can *locally, interactively* with `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`).<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, you must **make sure that the credentials** you're passing to `Invoke-Command -Credential` to connect to the remote machine with refer to a user account that (also) **has administrative privileges on the target machine, in which case the remote session *automatically and invariably* runs elevated** (with admin privileges).<sup>[2]</sup>

If you cannot pass such credentials, I think you're out of luck.

---

To **test if the current user has administrative privileges**:

```bash
# Returns $true if elevated, otherwise $false.
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
```

Separately, here's a **simple test you can run from *inside a session*** to determine **whether it is running with elevation**:

```bash
# Returns $true if elevated, otherwise $false.
[bool] (net session 2>$null)
```

---

<sup>[1] Unless the session at already *is* elevated, `-Verb RunAs` presents a pop-up UAC dialog that a user must confirm interactively, which is not supported in a remote session.</sup>

<sup>[2] The same applies if you use "loopback remoting", i.e. if you target the *local* machine via remoting, using `Invoke-Command -ComputerName .`, for instance, with additional restrictions, however: You cannot use a user that is authorized for remoting but isn't part of the local `Administrators` group, and if you use the *current* user (whether or not with explicit credentials), the *calling* session must itself be elevated.</sup>

Comment: Possibly worth noting that running `Invoke-Command` against the local computer also results in automatic elevation of the commands inside the script block, provided the account has administrative privileges.

Comment: Thanks. On your last sentence, I've found that I can open an unelevated Powershell window, and still elevate locally with `Invoke-Command`.  See Powershell output at https://pastebin.com/wqeUaC8R

Comment: Thanks, @Jimadine - I wasn't aware that if you specify a *different* user's credentials, elevation isn't required. I've updated the footnote to hopefully paint the full picture. Let me know if it matches your experience.

Comment: That makes sense. Yes, different user - I am opening the PS window as a standard user a/c, then entering an administrator a/c in the `Get-Credential` prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this:

```
$command = {
    Start-Process "powershell" -Verb runas -Workingdirectory "C:\Folder\" -ArgumentList "build.ps1"
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteSystemIP -ScriptBlock $command -credential $Credentials1 -ErrorAction Stop -AsJob
```

Comment: Its not executing the script within build.ps1

Comment: If the credentials are admin credentials, the remote session is _automatically_ elevated - no extra work needed; if they're not, trying to elevate on demand with `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` does _not_ work (no way to show the UAC GUI).