# How to use invoke command to install .msi file on remote system which requires elevated permissions

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to run an msiinstaller file on a remote system using the invoke-command.
I have tried a couple of different methods but both have been unsuccessful to this point.
They don't error out but they don't seem to run the install on the remote system either. At least as far as I can tell. Nothing in the event log, still on the old version of software I am trying to update.

I will post both methods here to see if either one of them is close and someone can get me over the top. thanks in advance. [I tend to get confused with how to properly use the invoke command so please cut me some slack if I am totally off base on these attempts.]

common for both:
using get-credential to load up var $cred
var targetHost is the remote system

first method:

```
$MsiInstallPath = "c:\Temp\MSI\file.msi"
$MsiArguments = " /i `"$MsiInstallPath`" /q SITE_TOKEN='adsfads' "
invoke-command -ComputerName $targetHost -Scriptblock { param($msi_args) Start-Process msciexec.exe -ArgumentList $msi_args } -ArgumentList $MsiArguments
```

second method:

```
$scriptblock = { Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $MsiInstallPath", "/q", "SITE_TOKEN='abcd'" }
invoke-command -ComputerName $targetHost -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Any insight or assistance would be most appreciated.
Thanks
D

Comment: Add `/l*v c:\Temp\MSI\install.log` to the `msiexec` arguments. It will contain details about any errors.

Comment: Second method is incorrect. Use `$using:MsiInstallPath` to refer to the variable which is declared outside of the script block. See [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-9--include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Regarding elevated permissions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024701/7571258).

Comment: There is no need to use `Start-Processs` here. Try this: `$MsiArguments = '/i', $MsiInstallPath, '/q', '/l*v C:\Temp\MSI\install.log', "SITE_TOKEN='adsfads'"; invoke-command -ComputerName $targetHost -Credential $cred -Scriptblock { msiexec $using:MsiArguments; "msiexec returned $LastExitCode" }` -- this will output [exit code of msiexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes) in case log file isn't written.

Comment: I used your code snippet and made my actual variable changes, but the LastExitCode came back blank when it completed. Nothing was in the \Temp\MSI\ for logs.

any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually you need `Start-Process` to get exit code from msiexec because it is a GUI process that normally runs detached. `$MsiArguments = '/i', $MsiInstallPath, '/q', '/l*v C:\Temp\MSI\install.log', "SITE_TOKEN='adsfads'"; 
invoke-command -ComputerName $targetHost -Credential $cred -Scriptblock { $exitCode = (Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $using:MsiArguments -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode; "msiexec returned $exitCode" }`

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm almost there but I'm getting a 1603 error code. But I wouldn't have gotten that far without your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: When you get an error 1603, search for "value 3" (localized in the actual language of the MSI) in the MSI log file. The actual cause of error is usually located a few lines before that.