# Trying to run Get-WindowsUpdate on a remote computer but get: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, windows-update

I've got a powershell script to remote into other computers to get and install windows updates.

I'm logged into the admin account on my local machine. The script starts a powershell remote session into another computer which works fine.

Then once in the remote session the script should run:

`Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot`

but i get this error:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate
```

I tried suggested solutions of changing the WMI permissions and I allowed this in the firewall settings but it still did not work.

Comment: Did you run the instance as admin? Logging into the account doesn't mean you're session becomes *elevated*.

Comment: I think you have to schedule the updates because of remote powershell permissions.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thanks for responding! yeah i ran as admin i believe. From the admin machine i run the the powershell window as administrator. Then i pass the admin credentials to log into remote computer. From what i read my remote session will automatically run with elevated privileges as the admin account has administrative privileges over the target machine: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022178/run-invoke-command-in-remote-computer-as-administrator)

Comment: @js2010 thanks for responding! do you mean use task scheduler to run the script instead?

Comment: Yes I think that command has options for it.

Comment: Similar problem - I am not able to remotely start update with Administrator user:
Get-WindowsUpdate : The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
It works fine for win2019 but fails on win2022(both remote machines)

Comment: Invoke-WUJob – remotely call WUJobs task in the Task Scheduler to immediately execute PSWindowsUpdate commands;

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully scripted it by using:

​

```
Get-WindowsUpdate -verbose -computer $RemoteServer -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot
```

Comment: thanks! but i still get the error: 

VERBOSE: Accepted [8] Updates ready to Download
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsUpdate], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,PSWindowsUpdate.GetWindowsUpdate